# iOS Swift: change defaultCalendarForNewEvents

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

I'm trying to change the default calendar for events and reminders.

If I try with:

```
store.defaultCalendarForNewEvents = myCalendar
```

I get: **Cannot assign to property: 'defaultCalendarForNewEvents' is a get-only property**

But I see that in the iOS settings it is possibile to change it.
How can I do that?

Comment: Only the user can change the default calendar that they want to use as it is a system-wide setting.  You can provide a picker that shows all calendars to let the user select the calendar they want to use for events created by your app.

Comment: You mean during the event creation or after the event is already created.. That is what I'm not looking for. Do you think is possible to redirect the user to the system settings where he can change the default calendar?

Comment: Changing the default calendar is a bit drastic.  In your app you can provide the ability for the user to select from available calendars.  You can then specify that calendar when you create the event.

Comment: I'm already doing that, do you know if there is a way to redirect the user to the calendar settings in the system?

Comment: There is no way to take them there directly.  You can only provide directions.

Comment: thank you, should I close the answer? or leave it open for others?